# Azure blob storage returns 404 with some files

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure blob storage setup with a couple of files in it.  I am able to download the files into a Stream when they are small (KB sized), but when the files are a little larger (MB sized) I get a 404 error.  I have manually downloaded from the portal one of the images that is returning 404 fine and have resized that image and then uploaded the smaller image back to the container and I can then grammatically download it into a stream.

Here is the code that I'm using to download the blob

```
private static byte[] PerformDownload(string fileName, CloudBlobContainer container)
        {
            var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
                var bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)memoryStream.Length);
                return bytes;
            }
        }
```

The container is passed into this method and as I mentioned I can download some files from the container without issue, but if you need that code I can add that as well

The container is retrieve using the standard examples that you find, but here is the code

```
 private static CloudBlobContainer GetContainer(string containerName)
        {
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);

            var container = CreateContainerIfNeeded(storageAccount, containerName);
            return container;
        }

        private static CloudBlobContainer CreateContainerIfNeeded(CloudStorageAccount storageAccount, string containerName)
        {
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

            container.CreateIfNotExists();

            return container;
        }
```

Also Case sensitivity is not the issue because the container's name is 2017-106 and the file is 4448.jpg.

Comment: Please add the code. Also please note that blob names are case sensitive so you will get 404 error if you provided the blob's name in different case (you request `myimage.png` when the blob is actually saved as `MyImage.png`).

Comment: I updated the question with the additional code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am able to download the files into a Stream when they are small (KB sized), but when the files are a little larger (MB sized) I get a 404 error.

Currently [max size of a block blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits) is approx. 4.75 TB, storing MB-sized data in a block blob, which should not cause Azure Blob service return 404 when you access the blob. [404 error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes) indicates that the specified blob does not exist, as Gaurav Mantri said,  [Blob name is case-sensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata), please make sure the `filename` (blob name) you provided indeed exists in your container.

Besides, If only that specific blob can not be found, but it is really existing in your container, you can create support request to report it.

Comment: The file is defiantly there and case sensitivity is not the problem because the container name is 2017-106 and the file name is 4448.jpg.

Comment: It was the case sesnsitivity the extension was .JPG not .jpg  Thanks for the help